# how to load js using wp_enqueue_script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to call js library using `wp_enqueue_script`. but I can't figure out what I'm mistaking here also, I want to use for plugins Please tell me how to use my plugins directory.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_script');
function add_custom_script(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 
    'jquery-custom-script',
    get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-custom-script.js'
 );
}
```

can anyone figure out what I'm mistaking here .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`plugin_dir_url`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) function.

**Example:**

```
/**
 * Include CSS file for MyPlugin.
 */
function myplugin_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'foo-js',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/foo-custom.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foo-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_scripts' );
```

If you pass `__FILE__` as argument of the get the current PHP script file path

Comment: @AnandChoudhary If this answer would be helpful to you then please mark it as approved so it could be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the JS from a plugin, let's say inside the plugins/my-plugin directory, and the code runs in a file directly inside plugins/my-plugin, do something like this (also added a parameter explicitly specifying jQuery as a dependency of your script):

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-custom-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/jquery-custom-script.js', ['jquery']);
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to insert js and css in a wordpress plugin is

first register your files and second use them.

```
 // register scripts and style on initialization
add_action('init', 'register_style');
function register_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'style', plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_register_script( 'scripts', plugins_url('/js/scripts.js', __FILE__));
}

// use the registered scripts and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');

function enqueue_style(){
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
   wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do something like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
```